# Understanding ./ in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I wanna know the difference between these two commands, i'm still new to linux.

```
./test.txt
```

and

```
test.txt
```

Help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former executes the script in a file called `test.txt` *in the current directory*.

The latter executes the script in a file called `test.txt` in the first directory specified in `$PATH` where a file of that name exists.